# Rewrite arguments before passing them to a command

Tags: shell-script, string, rtorrent

I use `rtorrent`.  When using magnetic-links, it creates a "meta"-file (.meta).  This gets the form of a long hexadecimal-number (0-9, A-F).  For example:

```
0123456789ABCDEF0123456.meta
```

To "use" an existing meta-file to start `rtorrent`, you can first "isolate" the file-name without the suffix (without ".meta").

```
0123456789ABCDEF0123456
```

This hexadecimal-number part is actually (always?) 41 characters long.

Then you must add the protocol before it and a list of trackers after.

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:0123456789ABCDEF0123456&tr=http://tracker1.com:80&tr=udp://tracker2.net:8080
```

It would be great if it was possible to change the list of trackers.  Ideally, the URLs for trackers should be read from a file with one tracker per line - adding `&tr=` where needed.  Trackers uses either http:// or udp:// as protocols, and often port-number must be specified (with `:port` at the end).

An *example* of an actual "tracker-tail" (the part after the hexadecimal-number) could be:

```
&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fglotorrents.pw%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969
```

It must however be possible to change these, and ideally they should be listed in a separate file.

Such a file could for example contain:

`trackers.txt`:

```
udp://tracker.coppersurfer.tk:80
udp://glotorrents.pw:6969/announce
udp://tracker.leechers-paradise.org:6969
udp://tracker.opentrackr.org:1337/announce
udp://exodus.desync.com:6969
```

(Note: Trackers also uses http:// as protocol)

The result, after removing `.meta"=` and adding `magnet:...` and `&tr=...` - in quotes to be sure `&` doesn't confuse `bash` - can then be passed to rtorrent as argument.

---

What I'd like is a script that can automate this conversion-process, and pass the result to `rtorrent`.  Preferably one that could take multiple meta-files as argument (e.g. expanded by `bash` from *.meta), and pass them all - converted - as arguments to one `rtorrent` instance (which the script starts).

```
rtorrent "magnet:...12345..." "magnet:...6789..." "magnet:...ABCD..."
```

Unfortunately, I'm really horrid at writing `bash`-scripts, so does anybody here know how something like this could be done?

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: @don_crissti  No, the protocol of trackers is either http:// or udp://.  The "prefix/protocol" of the magnet (before the hexadecimal) is always "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:"  Typical tracker "tail": &tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fglotorrents.pw%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969

Comment: Could you please edit your question to put that info in (properly formatted) rather than leaving it in the comments?

Comment: @user1700494  I thought the script may start/spawn `rtorrent` "internally".  But what `rtorrent` need would be one - or preferably several - argument(s) in the form I mentioned, where the hexadecimal parts were parsed from the file-names of the meta-files passed to the script as arguments (only the name - not the actual content of the file - would be used).  After the "converted" arguments were passed to `rtorrent`, `rtorrent` would "take over" the script, showing `rtorrent`'s interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a snippet do do the conversion in bash.

```
#!/bin/bash

# The array of results passed to rtorrent in the end
results=()

# The file listing the trackers is the first argument
trackers="$1"
shift
# create the tracker list url part.
# sed reads the file and puts '&tr=' before each line,
# then it replaces all : and / with the percent escaped version for urls.
# tr deletes all newlines (turning the text into one long line)
tracker_list_for_url="$(sed 's/^/&tr=/;s/:/%3A/g;s#/#%2F#g' < "$trackers" \
                        | tr -d '\n')"

# loop over arguments and add them to $results
for arg in "$@"; do
  # remove the extension
  hex_part="${arg%.meta}"
  # append to results array
  results+="magnet:?xt=urn:btih:$hex_part$tracker_list_for_url"
done
exec rtorrent "${results[@]}"
```

I don't yet understand which program in your scenario calls which program and when and how arguments are created and passed to other programs. So I made these assumptions:

1. you call your script with the tracker list file as 1st argument and the meta files as the rest of the arguments
2. your script should start `rtorrent`

If these assumptions are wrong please clarify or use the above script and adopt it to your need.

Comment: don_crissti is right, I'd like (if possible) to pass one or more meta-files - for example the result of bash expanding *.meta.  I guess the tracker-file could be passed as the first argument, but it would also be acceptable to "hardcode" it into the script (would perhaps be best) - or maybe as a shell-variable.  I can certainly use your script as it is, but it would be even better if it could take several meta-files as argument and pass them all as arguments to the same rtorrent.  Anyway, you gave me a great place to start...  Thanks!

Comment: I should add that the *content* of the meta-files aren't actually used by the script - only the *file-names* of the meta-files.  (rtorrent itself uses the content however)